# Bloquear digitação em campo date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tem como **Bloquear** *digitação* em campo **date** e **manter** a **popup** que carrega o **calendário**?

O problema é o seguinte:

```
<input type='date' id='data' name='data' max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required  />
```

Adicionei **data limite** ao `input date`.

Quando o **usuário** escolhe no **calendário** a **data**, lá, as **datas posteriores** à **data limite** estão *desativadas* para a *seleção*. No entanto, se o **usuário** resolver *digitar* a **data** ao invés de escolhê-la no **calendário**, então ele *conseguirá* digitar uma **data posterior** à **data limite**.

Como *contornar* esse **problema**?

Comment: Você esta usando qual plugin para abrir este calendário?

Comment: nenhum. é o do próprio HTML5

Comment: A sua intensão é bloquear usando o html?

Comment: <input type='date'

Comment: se possível. Ou então, se houver uma forma de não permitir a digitação de datas posteriores também resolve. Mas o objetivo seria HTML mesmo

Comment: Você sabe que se você fazer isso apenas no html isso é facilmente burlado, já que quando a pagina é carregada na maquina no usuário ele pode fazer o que quiser com ela, o ideal é você verificar isso depois da requisição no php, assim o usuário não vai ter acesso algum e assim você vai fazer um bloqueio mais efetivo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88800/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: sei sim, mas queria fazer dois 2 lados]

Comment: Você utiliza Jquery?

Comment: sim. utilizou sim

Comment: Um exemplo que resolve o seu problema https://jsfiddle.net/jo8sq0t4/ se a sua pergunta for reaberta eu posto este mesmo código como resposta.

Comment: resolveu, muito obrigado